# c# receive message using skype?

Tags: c#

is there a way i can receive messages using SKYPE4COM .dll?  I am sending messages to a specific user using skype.SendMessage(). How can i receive them? I am working in a form application in visual studio c# and i would like to make a windows form to pop up everytime i receive a message. I amusing skype4com.dll. Please help. 
Can you please write a little code that was testes and works? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official example is for Delphi: http://developer.skype.com/delphi-examples/chatmessages-pas

But you do it in the same way. Simply subscribe on the `OnMessageStatus` event.

did a bit of googling:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CMuSXQDMYs
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SkypeBot.aspx?q=skype4com+message+event+c%23

Comment: could you please give me an eq in c# or vb using skype4com dll? i don;t know from where to start in the eg u gave.  I am new to this stuff.thx

Comment: IChatMessage is the one with which i can receive the messages?

Comment: `skype.MessageStatus` event lets you receive incoming skype messages.

Comment: is there a way to gave multiple skype instances and get handle for each of them?

Comment: SO has a strict one question per entry policy. If you want to ask more questions then please click on the `Ask Question` button.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is very late but I think the code can help other programmers having the same problem (code from [vsnippets.com](https://vsnippets.com/snippet.php?s=580bedba8eab6&t=Set%20a%20message%20Listener%20-%20Skype%20API)):

```
Skype skype = new Skype();
skype.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(incommingMessage);

private void incommingMessage(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
{
    string sender = msg.Sender.Handle; // Skype name of sender!
    string message = msg.Body;         // Message content
    DateTime sendTime = msg.Timestamp; // Time when the sender has sended the message.

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Your contact {0} sended you a message at {1}:\n\n{2}", sender, sendTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff"), message), "New Message");
}
```

(Code not tested yet but it should work)